# Error with DataTable

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, t4

I have this error >>> Compiling transformation: The type 'DataTable' is not defined.

These are my assembly's

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="true" language="VB" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Diagnostics" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension=".vb" #>
```

... and the part of code where it occurs

```
Imports project.Entities
<#  
    Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=PC101\TEST;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True;"
    Dim objTabla As String
    Dim conjuntoDatos As String = objTabla & "Set"
    Dim objContext as String = "context" & objTabla

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        connection.Open()

        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break
        Dim mtable As DataTable = connection.GetSchema("Tables")

        For liRows As Integer = 0 To mtable.Rows.Count - 1
#> 
Public Sub New()
    context = New <#=objContext #>
    context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I´m tryng to make a t4 template with this code

Answer (score 0):

So the code snippet you have has a number of errors, the using statement is missing an end using, the for is missing a next, and the "objTabla" variable is used before it is initialized.  After I fixed all that I found out that you need to add a reference to System.Xml assembly.  Here is the complete template that should work:

```
<#@ template language="VB" hostspecific="true" debug="False" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
Imports project.Entities
<#  
    Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=PC101\TEST;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True;"
    Dim objTabla As String = ""
    Dim conjuntoDatos As String = objTabla & "Set"
    Dim objContext as String = "context" & objTabla

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        connection.Open()

        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break
        Dim mtable As DataTable = connection.GetSchema("Tables")

        For liRows As Integer = 0 To mtable.Rows.Count - 1

#> 
Public Sub New()
    context = New <#=objContext #>
    context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = False
End Sub
<# 
    next

    end using
 #>
```

If you are interested in how I figured this out, I used my extension [T4 Awesome](http://www.t4awesome.com) to debug and test your template.  Full Disclaimer, the features I used are in the full version which cost money (but you can try free for 14 days).  You could use the free community version and it would tell you the same thing but in a less friendly way, you would have to look at the raw log in the vs output window for the answers.